# Filter XML by node value in R

Tags: xml, r, xpath, nodes

I started programming in R today and I want to get some values based on an xml file (with the library "XML").

The XML below is a simplified version of the real one.

```
<PDBx:datablock xmlns:PDBx="http://pdbml.pdb.org/schema/pdbx-v40.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" datablockName="1AEW" xsi:schemaLocation="http://pdbml.pdb.org/schema/pdbx-v40.xsd pdbx-v40.xsd">
    <PDBx:atom_siteCategory>
      <PDBx:atom_site id="1">
        <PDBx:Cartn_x>22.250</PDBx:Cartn_x>
        <PDBx:Cartn_y>-18.232</PDBx:Cartn_y>
        <PDBx:Cartn_z>52.362</PDBx:Cartn_z>
        <PDBx:label_atom_id>N</PDBx:label_atom_id>
      </PDBx:atom_site>

      <PDBx:atom_site id="2">
         <PDBx:Cartn_x>22.188</PDBx:Cartn_x>
         <PDBx:Cartn_y>-19.614</PDBx:Cartn_y>
         <PDBx:Cartn_z>52.835</PDBx:Cartn_z>
         <PDBx:label_atom_id>CA</PDBx:label_atom_id>
      </PDBx:atom_site>
.
.
.
```

**What I need to extract is the (x, y, z) coordinates of all the "atom_site" nodes that have the value "CA" inside their "label_atom_id" node.**

I already searched and this is what I found:

```
nodes = getNodeSet(xmltop[[1]], "//atom_siteCategory/atom_site[@label_atom_id='CA']");
```

I use `xmltop[[1]]` because I want to search from the "atom_siteCategory" node. This is the node that contains all the "atom_site" nodes.

The problem with this XPATH is that `atom_site[@label_atom_id='CA]` works for node attributes, not node values.

In few words:
1) How to get the `atom_site` nodes with `"CA"` as the value of `label_atom_id`. 
(which XPATH to use)

2) How to extract the 3 coordinates (x,y,z) from those nodes. 
(How to fill a data.frame with this coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution:

```
#Changes program path to paramenter absolute path
setwd("C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/App")
#Let's user choose xml file (can be replaced with absolute path)
file = file.choose(new = FALSE)
#Pases xml file
xmlfile = xmlParse(file)
class(xmlfile)
#Gets top node
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile)
#Filters node with XPATH
nodes = getNodeSet(xmltop, "/PDBx:datablock/PDBx:atom_siteCategory/PDBx:atom_site[PDBx:label_atom_id='CA']")
#Turns node list into dataframe
extract = xmlSApply(nodes, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
df = data.frame(t(extract), row.names = NULL)
#Gets column subset (X, Y, Z) coordinates
df2 = df[, c(2,3,4)]
#Changes original names to X, Y and Z
df2 = setNames(df2, c("Cartn_x" = "X", "Cartn_y" = "Y", "Cartn_z" = "Z"))
#Prints the data frame
print.data.frame(df2)
```

I hope this helps somebody.